# using mark.js in a conditional case

Tags: javascript, regex

Im using mark.js to highlight positive vs negative statements such as,

"i am a banana"

versus

"i am not a banana"

How can I avoid adding the positive class to the term "not a banana"? (eg have the phrase "not a banana" being colored in red)

NB looking for a solution with the **instance.markRegExp** function

```js
var instance = new Mark(".bananas");

//negative
instance.markRegExp(/not a banana/g, {
  className: "negative"
});

//positive
instance.markRegExp(/a banana/g, {
  className: "positive"
});
```

```css
mark{
background: white;
}

.positive {
color: green;
}

.negative {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.8.3/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="bananas">
  i am a banana. <br> i am not a banana.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure that this is the right solution, but it works.

In your example, what happens is that both classes applied to the result.

So you can solve the issue by adding to a rule to CSS which means if positive is inside negative - show as negative.

```
.negative,
.negative .positive{
color: red;
}
```

```js
var instance = new Mark(".bananas");

//negative
instance.markRegExp(/not a banana/g, {
  className: "negative"
});

//positive
instance.markRegExp(/a banana/g, {
  className: "positive"
});
```

```css
mark{
background: white;
}

.positive {
color: green;
}


.negative,
.negative .positive{

color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.8.3/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="bananas">
  i am a banana. <br> i am not a banana.
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for a solution in the context of the instance.markRegExp function - +1 anyway